# Debugging Incorrectly Displaying Bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My bars should alternate through the background, similar to what is done in this jsFiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ny2FJ/18/). This is what it ends up looking like: [picture](http://postimg.org/image/lsyqkqxhl/).

This is the code that should do the trick (but doesn't):

```
svg.selectAll("g.grid")
    .data(y.ticks()).enter()
    .append("g").attr("class", "grid")
    .select("rect")
        .data(x.ticks())
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("y", function(d, i, j) {
                return yScale(i);
        })
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", (yScale.rangeBand()))
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return ((i) % 2) == 1 ? "white" : "lightgrey";
        });
```

And this is the entire code of what I'm working with: [code](http://codepaste.net/3uxqyy)

And a Fiddle of the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/35kn3a0f/1/).

Comment: Could you provide a working jsfiddle with your code that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff http://jsfiddle.net/35kn3a0f/result/

Comment: It's not displaying anything for me. Looks like you have a copy and paste error there and forgot to include the D3 library.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you are correct, sorry here's the correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/35kn3a0f/1/

Comment: You seem to have two sets of scales for both x and y. You're using one of them to get the tick values and the other to place the grid. I'd suggest using only one set of scales.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff something isn't working right. Maybe I'm just not understanding, but would you mind making a fiddle?

Comment: Well you have a fiddle that does exactly what you want already. I'd suggest that you go back and have a look at how it's different to what you had initially and then try to port those changes over. At the moment you seem to be quite confused about how the different things work together and I don't think that somebody just giving you a solution will help with that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I got it to work via a different way. I'll have answer posted tomorrow. Spent a day on this damn thing and and ended up just using grid lines and creating rectangles on every tick, literally something i came up with and solved in about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the grid lines that were already in my code as baselines for the rectangles. This is the code that makes the grid lines work:

```
function make_y_axis() {        // function for the y grid2 lines
    return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
}
```

And here is how they're called:

```
svg.append("g")      // Draw the y grid2 lines
    .attr("class", "grid2")
    .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    );
```

This creates my grids, and in CSS up top, I erase the lines, so they are there, but can not be seen.

```
.grid2 .tick {
    stroke: none;               
}
```

And to almost finish it off, I actually add the rectangles like so:

```
svg.selectAll(".grid2")
    .selectAll(".tick")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", maxY - 4.03)
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
            return ((i) % 2) == 1 ? "zebraGrey" : "zebraNone";
        })
        .attr("stroke", "none");
```

And add the styling:

```
.zebraNone {
    opacity: 0;
}
.zebraGrey {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.05;
}
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You had everything right except for your y had the wrong elements